# How to define the user level when creating a new account?

Tags: laravel-8

I am currently using this code in laravel to create a new account, but I want to retrieve the ID generated for this account

```
return User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
]);
```

I want to do this, to also give permission to the police

```
$data['id']->syncRoles($data['roles']),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create method return the created elocuent model, and you can manage like:

```
$user = User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
]);
if($user)
  $user->syncRoles($data['roles']);

return $user;
```